# Font Selection for Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, look-and-feel

I am bit confused about chosing font for my winform application.

I want to chose a font which will go smoothly on Win7/XP/Vista. My application has been designed with windows Office2007 like bluish theme, and also has future requirement about provision for selecting other standard themes.

Currently all my user controls/forms and all other controls have arial fond. But it doesn;t look cool.

Can anybody know any good tricks/tips to chose a smart font for winapp?
Or are there any guidelines to check for cool fonts for your apps?

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance,
Kapil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a bug in Winforms [2008] where the default system font is not used. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297701/default-font-for-windows-forms-application) and [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/KDente/archive/2005/03/13/394499.aspx) for more info, but the trick is to set the default app font to `SystemFonts.MessageBoxFont` which will give the correct system font. Make all your forms and controls inherit this, and the app will use the system font.

Answer (score 4):

Use the system default. In Windows Vista and 7 that would be Segoe UI. It makes your app look consistent in the rest of the OS; otherwise, it will just stand out, and not always in a good way.